# Regex match all subdirectories of a given directory but exclude said directory

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm trying to match all the subdirectories of the `match` directory but excluding the `match` directory.

```
www.domain.com/match/subdirectory1                 #good
www.domain.com/match/subdirectory2                 #good
www.domain.com/match/subdirectory2/subdirectory3/  #good
www.domain.com/match/                              #bad
```

Thanks!

Comment: 1) You said you were trying, but you did not post an attemp - please do. 2) You say you want to *match* but *exclude* and then state you have "good" and "bad" strings - so, what are you really doing? What is the expected output for each string?

Comment: My attempt was: `.*\/match\/[^\/].*` because I thought that if after the slash's match is followed by anything else then it would have a subdirectory, which are the ones that I want to select.

What I want is to select all the url that matches the given criteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

`/www.domain.com\/match\/([0-9A-Za-z]+\/?)+/`

Edit: for multiple directories after match directory

Comment: Thank you! That was the solution to my problem! Cheers.